# Filter, Group by, and count unique values in each group in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

How can I filter where `State = AA`, group by `Store` and count the number of unique values in `Item` in Power BI?

```
    YearMonth   State   Store   Qty  Sales          Item
0   2020-06     AA      JW442   1.0  100            SP006
1   2020-06     AA      JW442   1.0  1200           SP007
2   2019-09     CC      JW600   4.0  700            SP020
3   2019-05     AA      JW100   5.0  30             SP00
4   2019-05     AA      JW100   4.0  8500           SP5
                                ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this measure:

```
 Measure = CALCULATE( COUNTROWS(values(tabx[Item])), filter(ALL('tabx'[State]), 'tabx'[State] = "AA"))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi msta42a, thanks for the answer. Can I please ask if you have grouped the data by `Store`? If not, how did you get `Store` as the first column in the output table? In my case I got only one value instead of a table.

Comment: Just create new table visualization in powerbi, select from column your "Store" and add measure. Powerbi do everything automatic (grouping and summarizing)